# jQuery not calculating offsets correctly after using .css method

Tags: jquery

I have used jQuery to add heights and calculate offset here (example code):

```
var winHeight = window.innerHeight;
var $blur_feature = $('.blur_feature');

$element_inside_body.css('height, winHeight');

var blur_feature_offset = $blur_feature.offset().top;
console.log(blur_feature_offset);
```

When I console log the offset, it is not correct. When I set a timeout of say 3 seconds and log the offset, sometimes it is correct.

Are there any known issues with the .css method and calculating offset? Can't find anything on this at all on the internet.

Im adding a height an element inside of the body, but it's affecting the offset of other elements on the page because the height is changed. I can't find a way to find a way of detecting if the .css method is finished so jQuery knows to calculate the offset after the extra heights to the body have been appled. (I'm setting heights on many elements).

Comment: run the function after everythings is loaded/rendered

Comment: Do you mean $(window).on(‘load’)? If so, I tried this and nothing changes

Comment: console log winHeight as well... maybe you can create a jsfiddle.